# php database connection/selection

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `login.html` in which the `form` is defined as follows:

```
<form method="post" action= "do_authorize.php"  name="lform">
  <span class="style1">First Initial Plus Last Name :</span>  
    <input type="text" name="user" size="25">
    <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

My `do_authorize` is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();

require('../databaseConnectionFileFolder/dbconnection.php');

$user             = $_POST["user"]; 

var_dump($user);

$_SESSION['username']=$user;

var_dump($user);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $table_name_users WHERE username = \"$user\"";

var_dump($sql);

$result=@mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die("couldn't execute query");

$num=mysql_numrows($result);
if ($num != 0) {

/*$cookie_name="$user";
$cookie_value="ok";
$cookie_expire=time()+86400;
$cookie_domain=".columbia.edu";

setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_expire, "/", $cookie_domain, 0);
*/
    print "<script>";
    print "self.location='somethingelse.php';";
    print "</script>";

} else {
echo "<p>you're not authorized";
}


?>
```

My `dbconnection.php` file is as follows:

```
<?php

$db_server      = "localhost"; 
$db_name        = "DailyExerciseDB"; 
$db_user        = "abc5"; //the database username

//$db_password      = "123"; // the database user pasword

$connection=@mysql_connect($db_server,$db_user) or die("Could Not Connect to the Database :   ". mysql_error());
var_dump($connection);
$db=@mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die("Could Not Select the Database". mysqli_connect_error());

//var_dump($db);


?>
```

My Questions:
1) I keep on getting `Could Not Select the Database`, why does the warning/error message corresponding to `. mysqli_connect_error()` doesn't get printed on the browser?

2) I have manually entered the user with username `abc5` in the database and still it's not able to connect.Does anyone know why?

3) Even if I don't enter anything in the `login.html` and press `login` button, the following files gets executed, how can I take `user` entered into account while verifying with database? I believe since its hardcoded right now `abc5`, all files are getting executed.

4) `var_dump($connection);` prints `resource(4, mysql link)`

Comment: For question #1: You can't use `mysqli_connect_error` with `mysql_` functions; they're entirely different libraries. Mixing and matching is a big no-no.

Comment: Okay, what can I use instead of that?

Comment: `mysql_error()` just like you did *in the code two lines above that one*.

Comment: Having said that: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: Not a dupe @aynber - OP is missing a password for the database connection.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The username I have added in the database and I am not sure what password I should be passing.

Comment: You have no `$db_pass`. That is what you need to add.

Comment: @JayBlanchard How should I add? And it will be user specific?

Comment: `$db_pass = the_database_password;` and then `$connection=@mysql_connect($db_server,$db_user, $db_pass)`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Good point. It was just one issue of several. :/

Comment: @JayBlanchard I understood what code changes are required but How can I figure out what is the password? I haven't set any password. Thanks again.

Comment: Then set `$db_pass = '';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_connect()` has a third parameter which I'm not seeing you use: the password. Consider the following line:

```
mysql_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_password);
```

Also, you should probably be using `mysqli` extension instead of the `mysql` extension (`mysql` is deprecated in PHP 5.5.0).

I also see you're mixing the `mysql` and `mysqli` functions in your code. This is the reason why `mysqli_connect_error()` shows nothing.

Comment: The username I have added in the database and I am not sure what password I should be passing.